Questions about blender cell fracture
How can I break an object unit in blender so that the fragments can just form the shape of another object? For example, I built a bottle with a flower texture. After breaking the bottle unit, the broken fragments can just form the flower on the texture.
For example, how can the bottle on the left of the picture completely overlap with the black petals on the right after cell fracture?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The Cell Fracture tool is to generate more or less random pieces. If you want pieces in specific shapes, just build a model containing objects in these specific shapes. And then probably just fracture are parts that are not required to have a specific shape.
